# shell script string substitution

Tags: file, shell, sh, substitution

I have printable text in a file (header.txt):

```
*******************
* $string
*******************
```

and I have the script (generate.sh):

```
prn_header () {
   string=$1
   echo $(<header.txt)
}

prn_header I_want_this_text_for_the_header
```

and the output is exactly the same like the header.txt.

My problem is: how can I get the template from a file, but substitute the needed variable in it before printing?

In real, I have many text pieces in files, and the result builded from them.

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/TemplateFiles

Comment: By the way -- do you trust your templates to not be malicious? That is to say, is it a problem if a template containing `$(rm -rf ~)` were to have that code executed on evaluation?

Comment: Okay, thanks, I found it. :)